# App stuck on white screen after updating app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

App stuck on white screen after updating app from Google Play Store. 
And when we uninstall the previous version and re-install the app again from play store, the app runs fine. Has anyone else faced a similar issue ? Is there any solution for this ?

In my config.xml I've already specified  But still the issue persists.

Comment: Sounds like persistent store or sqlite db isn't compatible between versions and isn't being correctly updated.

Comment: Does this mean we need to change the version during the call to method window.opendatabase(), even if we have not changed the schema of the sqlite db used?
We have not even changed the phonegap version used.
Changes were made to HTML part of the application only.

Actually, our app is a map based app developed in Sencha touch, which loads map from Google API from a URL mentioned in <script> tag i.e. <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=panoramio"></script>.

Comment: If you aren't changing the db schema or how the data from the db are used, then the problem lies elsewhere. I don't have any suggestions other than that you try to replicate the problem on a device where you can debug. Does the problem happen if you update the app by sideloading or is it entirely associated with Google Play Store updates?